# Prepared Statements in a PHP database connection class

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli, prepared-statement

I understand how prepared statements work (outside of a function). But what has really got me confused is how prepared statements would work inside a function for a class file.

For example, if the usage of a prepared statement is:

```
$dbc->select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = ?');
```

But, I don't know how I am confusing myself about how a user would use $dbc->select(); function inside a class file, create a query and then use prepared statements to execute the query.

Would it be something as simple as have the user write the query and then give the variables as another parameter, such as:

```
$dbc->select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = ?', 'Bob');
```

Or would I have it as seperate variables for the user to fill, which will then be built into a prepared statement, such as:

```
$dbc->select($columns, $table, $variables = array());
```

or would that over complicate things? I could also have another function that selects a specific row.

I feel option 1 is the better choice, but it seems not as user friendly? Or am I just so tired that I am overthinking complete sh**?

Anyways, I hope this all makes sense, and I apologize for any mistakes - I was nearly falling asleep whilst typing this! Maybe it's time to call it a night.

Thanks,
Kieron

Comment: Is your goal to make it more advanced, such as a query builder or just a wrapper around a standard statement execution and return?

Comment: Okay as I have just woken up, I can explain it better (as I'm no longer tired). What I am trying to do is create a database class that will have the common mysqli functions such as select, insert, delete, update, etc. So they would use my own made functions to query the database. The problem I am having is I am getting confused over how I can use prepared statements when the user is giving the query (How would I know what column, table, etc) I gave some examples in my post about ways I have thought of, but I'm not sure if they are the best options.

Comment: No one can explain how prepared statements should be used in a function such as $dbc->select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ");?

Comment: All your examples are viable in a class. That can all be made to work. Your second one would probably be the best thought. The second Parameter would be optional.

Comment: Also you would want to feed in an array, not just one value, unless you make an if condition to handle it, which is easy enough I guess.

Comment: Also you probably wouldn't call it `select` because you could just as easily update or insert with it. Probably just `query` is better.I should note these are all just opinion based on my own experience making a query engine.

Comment: I am also basing this on a pdo connection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, all of these are doable:

**Instance one:**

```
class qEngine 
    {
        private $con,
                $bind,
                $query;

        public function __construct($con)
            {
                $this->con = $con;
            }
        public function addParams($array)
            {
                $i = 0;
                foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                    $bKey = ":{$i}";
                    $this->bind[$bKey] = $value;
                    $i++;
                }
                return $this;
            }
        public function query($sql)
            {
                if(!empty($this->bind)) {
                    $this->query = $this->con->prepare($sql);
                    $this->query->execute($this->bind);
                }
                else {
                    $this->query = $this->con->query($sql);
                }
                return $this;
            }
        public function getResults()
            {
                while($result = $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $row[] = $result;
                }
                return (!empty($row))? $row : 0;
            }
    }
```

**Your example:**

```
$dbc->select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = ?');
```

**Would have to be something like:**

```
// $con would be a PDO connection
$qEngine = new qEngine($con);
$results = $qEngine     ->addParams(array('Bob'))
                        ->query('select * from users where firstname = :0')
                        ->getResults();
print_r($results);
```

**Instance two:**

```
class qEngine 
    {
        private $con,
                $bind,
                $query;

        public function __construct($con)
            {
                $this->con = $con;
            }
        private function addParams($array = false)
            {
                if(empty($array))
                    return false;

                $i = 0;
                foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                    $bKey = ":{$i}";
                    $this->bind[$bKey] = $value;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        public function query($sql,$bind = false)
            {
                $this->addParams($bind);

                if(!empty($this->bind)) {
                    $this->query = $this->con->prepare($sql);
                    $this->query->execute($this->bind);
                }
                else {
                    $this->query = $this->con->query($sql);
                }
                return $this;
            }
        public function getResults()
            {
                while($result = $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $row[] = $result;
                }
                return (!empty($row))? $row : 0;
            }
    }
```

**Your example:**

```
$dbc->select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = ?",'Bob');
```

**Would have to be something like:**

```
// $con would be a PDO connection
$qEngine    =   new qEngine($con);
$results    =   $qEngine    ->query('select * from users where firstname = :0',array('Bob'))
                            ->getResults();

print_r($results);
```

Instance three would have to be more complex since you have to build the sql automatically. I have one that I use that is similar, but it's complex.

Anyway, this is roughly how I would do it. One note, I haven't used these extensively but they should work provided you have a proper pdo connection injected in the construct.

Comment: Ah, perfect! This has made it so much clearer now. So I can just do this for different specific functions for common sql functions. Thanks!